# How to Monitor an existing Java class with JMX?

Tags: java, jmx

I have an existing Java class as follows and I want to monitor number of method invocations for each method in this class using JMX. How do I do it? I tried google but I can't see the big picture on how the whole thing is connected. It would be great if I can see see some code examples

```
Public class RPCServer {

   public void storeSchema() { // want to count number of method invocations
       System.out.println("storeSchema");
   }

   public void getSchema() { // want to count number of method invocations
       System.out.println("getSchema");
   }

   public void storeRow() { // want to count number of method invocations
       System.out.println("storeRow");
   }

   public void getRow() {  //want to count number of method invocations
       System.out.println("getRow");
   }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I you want to see how many time some methods are executed through JMX, I propose this solution

First you need an interface for your class. Only the methods of this interface are visible for JMX:

```
public interface RPCServerInterface {
  int countMethodInvocation(String method);
}
```

Then in the class you store how many time each function is call.

```
public class RPCServer implements RPCServerInterface{
  private int row;
  private Map<String,Integer> countByMethod = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

  // +1 to the number of time of execution of this method
  private void sumMethodInvocation(String method) {
   if ( countByMethod.containsKey(method) ) {
     int n = countByMethod.get(method);
     countByMethod.put(method, n+1);
   } else {
     countByMethod.put(method,1);
   }
  }

  // how many time the method has been invoked 
  @Override
  public int countMethodInvocation(String method){
    return countByMethod.containsKey(method)?countByMethod.get(method):0;
  }

  public void setRow(int i) { 
    // register each time is executed
    this.sumMethodInvocation("setRow"); 
    this.row = i;
  }
  public int getRow() {
    // register each time is executed
    this.sumMethodInvocation("getRow");
    return row;
  }
}}
}
```

Then you have to register your Bean:

```
MBeanServer mBeanServer = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
RPCServer rpcServer =  new RPCServer();
ObjectName objectName = new ObjectName("org.foo.RPCServer.jmx:type=RPCServerInterface");

StandardMBean standardMBean = new StandardMBean(rpcServer,RPCServerInterface.class);
mBeanServer.registerMBean(standardMBean, objectName);
```

The path org.foo.RPCServer.jmx is arbitrary.

Then your run jconsole and you find the process you are running.

[image: jconsole choose processs]

Then you can run the command countMethodInvocation and you can get the number of execution time.

Like this:

[image: Run program jconsole]

This tutorial can be useful:

[what-is-jmx-mbean-jconsole-tutorial](http://www.journaldev.com/1352/what-is-jmx-mbean-jconsole-tutorial)

Comment: Hi!! Thank you so much for this. Where do I put the code for registering my bean?

Comment: In some place of your application, maybe just after the main.

Comment: If you feel that I answer your question, check my answer :p

Comment: Last question. Why do I need to create an interface of existing methods from an existing class? Like in this case setRow, getRow? can I just have countMethodInvocation?

Comment: Hi! the jmx console tutorial link is broken but I was able to google and start jconsole by issuing jconsole pid_of_my_application and I was able to see the screen where countMethodInvocation but when I pass getRow the JConsole throws "problem invoking countMethodInvocation : java.lang.NullPointerException". any idea?

Comment: only you have to put in the interface the method that you want to access by the jconsole, yes, you can just have countMethodInvocation

Comment: I don't know way you have a NullpointerException, I used this code and it work for me, try executing that function in a test or in the main a see why you have a NullpointerException, maybe you don't initializate a variable

Comment: the NullPointerException is happening because countMethod.get under counterMethodInvocation is failing. so I changed it to this   
    @Override
    public int countMethodInvocations(String methodName) {
        if (countByMethod.containsKey(methodName)){
            return countByMethod.get(methodName);
        }
        return 0;
    }
   but now I always get 0 when I pass getRow from JConsole however when I log the entire countByMethod hahsmap I can see that the map is populated with non zero values. so I am not sure what is going on with passing parameters from JConsole?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111341/discussion-between-troncador-and-user1870400).

Comment: I think my answer solve your question, please put check if it is the case